# Match on 2 values?

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have person data

Employee ID || Length of Service || Age

and a Payment table
Length of Service || Age || Paid weeks

I want to return Paid weeks for each of the person data. How would i go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a universe? Does the universe connect the Person  and Payment tables?

Comment: As far as I know there's no lookup functionality in WebI. So you can merge datasets which have both the information by common columns (if they are different sources for report) or just add new dimension (or measure) [Paid weeks] to your table and get that data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go is to join those tables on universe level.

Alternatively you can load the two tables with two queries, and merge 'Length of Service' and 'Age'. This can be done by selecting both values, and right-click 'Merge'. Now you should be able to create a table where all four different columns are shown.

In case you are unable to create this table, you could make a variable containing the information of 'Length of Service' and 'Age', and make a detail of 'Paid weeks'.